# How can I match any substring except a particular one in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I want to write a regular expression that will match the following string

> a (any substring except 'ABC') ABC

An example for this would be `a   pqrs h js ABC`
The tricky part is to match any substring except 'ABC'. **Since the document in which I am searching for, can contain multiple lines that contain such pattern and I want to find all the lines separately I can't use the following expression**

> a.*ABC

because this would just give me the line where the first a is found extending uptill where the last 'ABC' is found in the document.

There is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/538191) which says I can use look ahead negation but that is not working in python, or maybe in my case because there is substring before and I have not tested simply using that expression because it will not serve my purpose

Comment: You have not said what you want to achieve. Please explain.

Comment: I think I have made it clear I want to find all the indices where such pattern exists. I will make use of .finditer to get all such locations in the document.

Comment: No, if you had, I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: Please see the lines that I have made bold in my question, I feel that I had made it clear what I want to achieve

Comment: Not even remotely the same thing.

Comment: I would not like to argue with you. Anyways I have got my answer, so at least my question was clear to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the non greedy quantifier i.e `?`

```
^a.*?ABC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  It worked. I am new at regular expressions, if possible can you explain why `?` is called non greedy quantifier

Comment: @Sachin: Have a look at this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html , it will explain better than I.